# what is the web address where my files are stored on Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, url

I would like to link a logo to paypal for gift certificates and it's asking for the URL.  What is the URL for Ubuntu One's folders?

Answer (score 1):

https://one.ubuntu.com/ is the URL to the base site.

If you want to 'publish' a file you will click on 'more' at the right of the file name. Then click the option to publish it. When you do that you will see a URL that the file is published too. (see below)

[image]

I hope this helps with your question.